# Scala Anonymous Function Defined as Composition of Two Functions

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I am a beginner in Scala, and currently studying the fascinating concept of anonymous functions.
However, my following attempt at defining one results in a compilation error:

```
def double(f:Int => Int): Int => Int = f(f(_))
println(double(_ * 2)(4))

[error]  found   : Int => Int
[error]  required: Int
[error]   def double(f: Int => Int): Int => Int = f(f(_))
[error]                                              ^
```

It seems that applying the function twice to the underscore doesn't work, but why?

The following functions are compiled successfully:

```
def double(f:Int => Int): Int => Int = x => f(f(x))
def apply(f:Int => Int): Int => Int = f(_)
```

I feel like the two implementations of `double` should be equivalent, since it replaces the argument `x` that is used only once in the body, but they are clearly different in the compiler's view.

I guess what I'm trying to ask is, why the first implementation of `double` fails while the second succeeds. Should the underscore be somehow 'directly' used in the function body? What would that mean exactly?

Comment: My personal advice, don't use the `_` syntax. It just adds more trouble that the few characters it saves. - PS: You can just do `f andThen f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double for example can look like (if you want anonymous function syntax):

```scala
def double(f:Int => Int): Int => Int = f.andThen(f)(_) // or (f andThen f)(_)
```

Or simply via function composition:

```scala
def double(f:Int => Int): Int => Int = f andThen f
```

`f(_)` will be expanded as `x => f(x)` so `f(f(_))` is treated as `f(x => f(x))`.

Answer (score 4):

`f(_)` is a shorthand for `x => f(x)`, i.e. it's a function.

In `f(f(_))` you apply the outer `f` to this function i.e. it's `f(x => f(x))`. That's why it doesn't compile.